# как встроить итератор или генератор в уже написанный парсер python?

Tags: python

есть файл логов с ошибками, написал парсер без использования генератора/итератора
нужно каким то образом модифицировать его, чтобы встроить туда либо генератор либо итератор
как встроить, не могу понять.
вот сам код парсера:

```
class Parser:

    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.dates = {}
        self.j = 17
        self.date_str = ''

    def parse_file(self):
        with open(self.file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            for line in file:
                if 'NOK' not in line:
                    continue
                self.counter(line=line)

    def counter(self, line):
        self.date_str = line[1:self.j]
        if self.date_str in self.dates:
            self.dates[self.date_str] += 1
        else:
            self.dates[self.date_str] = 1

    def result(self):
        for k, v in self.dates.items():
            print(f'[{k}] {v}')

    def run(self):
        self.parse_file()
        self.result()



file_name = 'events.txt'
parse = Parser(file_name=file_name)
parse.run()
```